# Access violation writing location 0x00DF0024

Tags: c++, pointers, access-violation

Can someone teach me what's the error in my code? The exception is thrown at line `ifs >> Acc[i].num_followers;`. Am I facing any pointer issues?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Followers {
    string title = "", tag = "";
    int num_followers = 0;
};

void readInput(Followers Acc[], int& totalAccount) {
    ifstream ifs("Followers.txt");
    for (int i = 0; !ifs.eof(); i++) {
        getline(ifs, Acc[i].title);
        getline(ifs, Acc[i].tag);
        ifs >> Acc[i].num_followers;
        totalAccount += 1;
    }
}

int main() {
    Followers acc[5];
    int total = 0;
    readInput(acc, total);
    cout << total;
    return 0;
};
```

This is the text file.

```
Instagram
@instagram
290000000
Cristiano Ronaldo
@cristiano
160000000
The Rock
@therock
137000000
Ariana Grande
@arianagrande
150000000
Selena Gomez
@selenagomez
148000000
```

Comment: `!ifs.eof()` could cause bad behavior. Also your code has no checking for keeping inside the bounds of the array.

Comment: May i know the details?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: Your code would be better if you used `std::vector<Followers>` instead of the fixed sized array.

Comment: This might be worth a read too: [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: Did you try using a debugger? A debugger will easily show all the problems in the shown code. Like how it's not reading what you think it does, because of mixing `>>` together with `std::getline`. And after this is fixed the broken eof logic results in one extra iteration, and more demons flying of of everyone's nose because of complete lacks of bounds checking resulting in an array overrun.

Comment: Ya I just add one more ifs.ignore(); below the ifs >> Acc[i].num_followers; and then the bug is fixed.

Comment: Ok thanks I will go and check the bounds of the array.